# Query optimization, timeout error in c#

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there any better way to write the below query for optimize the performance.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MBQ_All] ([Uniq], [StoreClass], [Store], [code], [ExtendedDescription], [ITEM_CLASS], [SUPPLIER], [Brands], [Min], [Max],[ADS]
           ,[Store+whMBQ])

    SELECT [Uniq], [StoreClass], [Store], [code], [ExtendedDescription], [ITEM_CLASS], [SUPPLIER], [Brands], [Min], [Max],[ADS]
           ,[Store+whMBQ]
    FROM dbo.MBQ_All_1
    WHERE MBQ_All_1.Uniq NOT IN (
            SELECT UNIQ
            FROM dbo.MBQ_All
            );
```

The table **MBQ_All** has more than 4,00,000 Rows and **MBQ_All_1** has 2,00,000.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: can you please share a schema and an EXPLAIN? Is there an index on uniq?

Comment: There is one non clustered index in the table no uniq index exists..

Comment: You will almost certainly get a significant improvement from putting an index on the uniq column on both tables.

Comment: Yes along with following Query fix added unique column to the table . Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try using NOT EXISTS:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MBQ_All] ([Uniq], [StoreClass], [Store], [code], [ExtendedDescription], [ITEM_CLASS], [SUPPLIER], [Brands], [Min], [Max],[ADS]
       ,[Store+whMBQ])

SELECT [Uniq], [StoreClass], [Store], [code], [ExtendedDescription], 
[ITEM_CLASS], [SUPPLIER], [Brands], [Min], [Max],[ADS] ,[Store+whMBQ]
FROM dbo.MBQ_All_1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM dbo.MBQ_All
              WHERE dbo.MBQ_All.UNIQ = MBQ_All_1.Uniq)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is taking only 4 secs, before it was more than 1 minute

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a clear case for [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) statement:

```
MERGE [dbo].[MBQ_All] Tgt
USING [dbo].[MBQ_All_1] Src ON Tgt.Uniq = Src.Uniq
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (    [Uniq],     [StoreClass],     [Store],     [code],     [ExtendedDescription],     [ITEM_CLASS],     [SUPPLIER],     [Brands],     [Min],     [Max],     [ADS],     [Store+whMBQ])
    VALUES (Src.[Uniq], Src.[StoreClass], Src.[Store], Src.[code], Src.[ExtendedDescription], Src.[ITEM_CLASS], Src.[SUPPLIER], Src.[Brands], Src.[Min], Src.[Max], Src.[ADS], Src.[Store+whMBQ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the options would be to have LEFT JOIN, but I am not sure if it will be faster:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MBQ_All] 
     ([Uniq], [StoreClass], [Store], [code], [ExtendedDescription], [ITEM_CLASS], [SUPPLIER], [Brands], [Min], [Max],[ADS]               ,[Store+whMBQ])

    SELECT [Uniq], [StoreClass], [Store], [code], [ExtendedDescription], [ITEM_CLASS], [SUPPLIER], [Brands], [Min], [Max],[ADS]
           ,[Store+whMBQ]
    FROM dbo.MBQ_All_1 mbqN
    LEFT JOIN MBQ_All mbqO ON mbqN.Uniq =  mbqO.Uniq
    WHERE mbqO.Uniq IS NULL
```

Comment: It is still better than the query I wrote , thank you !